# SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems like an error you would receive in your early days of coding and for the life of me, I can not figure out why I am receiving this error.

My code is as follows:

```
Order.joins(:all_adjustments).where(all_adjustments.last: { source_type: "Spree::PromotionAction" } )
```

Please, any help would be appreciated! I have a feeling I am missing something stupidly obvious...I just can't tell what the heck it is!

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input: "Spree::PromotionAction" } )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relationship `has_many :all_adjustments, class_name: 'Spree::Adjustment'`, all_adjustments is just a custom name to define the relationship between an order and his adjustments (that's why the class_name is specify)

In the case of your query, you need to joins the association name (so `all_adjustments`) ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations))
With the result of this join, you may create a condition which uses any of the **tables** in the join.([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)). In your case the table name is `spree_adjustments`.

So your query should work this way:

```
Spree::Order.joins(:all_adjustments).where(spree_adjustments: { source_type: "Spree::PromotionAction" } )
```

Comment: Perfect! `spree_adjustments` fixed my issue. Thank you very much @sovalina

Answer (score 4):

It's due to `where(all_justments.last:`, which is invalid syntax.

The argument of `where` needs to be a hash, and what you have there isn't a valid hash.  If you want to use the `{key: value}` syntax in your hash, `key` must be a symbol, and you are trying to put an expression there instead.

Try instead

```
Order.joins(:all_adjustments).where(all_adjustments: { source_type: "Spree::PromotionAction" } )
```

That may not work depending on how you've set up your relations, but it should get you closer to the real error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that and it did remove the error but now it is saying

`NameError: uninitialized constant Order`

I am using spree and going off of the repo 

For Adjustment https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/adjustment.rb

For order 
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb

What changes would need to be made based on those links?

Comment: @belshnickleson97 If you're using spree the model name is `Spree::Order` not `Order`

Comment: @sovalina Understood and I have made that change. Did you take a look at the links I attached? I am not sure how to handle `all_adjustments` Should that be `Spree::Adjustment`? In the code for Spree it looks like `Spree::Order` `has_many :all_adjustments` but specify's the class name as `Spree::Adjustments` so the fact that those two names are different is why I believe I am having trouble with this query

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to query for? It's a bit difficult to help until we know what you are trying to do.